# How does one use Google Guice's @Inject with Scala / (Play 2.4.x)

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, guice

I'm ready to drink the koolaid :)

Play is moving to Google Guice (https://github.com/google/guice) so I guess I've got no real choice here but to tag along for the ride.

Somehow I'm missing something however.

I get the "don't call us we'll call you" mentality and the core reason for a Dependency Injection solution - less brittle and more testable code.

Sometimes however all I want is just a simple toothpick and don't feel the need to bake a cake, or worse yet write the complete recipe for baking one, just to get one...

Scala, the language seems to have made toothpick factories trivial (One of Guice's arguments is the cost of building factories (in Java) -- so to me that argument is off the table at least but that does't negate the rest of the DI issues I know).

In scala you have a Companion `object` (sorry having a Serenity flashback -- I need a moment - ok good to go  -- oh and blame Odersky for that combination of words not me please...).

For the Toothpick class:

```
case class Toothpick(color: Color) 

object Toothpick {
  def redPlease = {
    Toothpick(Color.RED) 
  }
}
```

Of course you can get fancy with the `apply` and a host of other scala niceties to get the exact Toothpick you want merely by referring the `Toothpick` "object":

```
val myShinyRedToothpick = Toothpick.redPlease
```

So in this case `Toothpick` the `object` is an instant factory.

Making something easy does not make it right -- it just makes it easy.

The overview of Google's Guice seems to be: ***One Factory to Rule Them All***.

Ok - I can live with that. They got their first -- they own all the land -- we'll be sharecroppers forever. Game over.

What I need is the toothpick example of how to **USE** a Guice'd up factory. How do I get my freaking toothpick from within **NORMAL** Scala code please?

(Like I said I could be completely missing the point... so the feel free to hurl whatever monkey crap is needed to get me to look in the right direction if that is the case).

PS: I do not need a lesson in **WHY** - I merely want one in **HOW**.

Comment: Odersky used "companion module". They got tired of explaining that you define a module with keyword object.

Comment: @som-snytt ah interesting tidbit of history. Thanks --amusing how a simple single word can be so misunderstood :)

Comment: Came across this - it might help... http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-guice/

Comment: You can get singletons from Guice, or an annotated instance, etc. https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InstanceBindings

Comment: That is the *binding* side of the deal - I want the unbinding side of things - how to I *use* a class/singleton/method/field pulled out of the Guice's blender...(or perhaps how do I *pluck*...)

Comment: You ask the injector for the root object, and all other dependencies are injected. Random example https://github.com/rocketraman/activator-akka-scala-guice/blob/master/src/main/scala/Main.scala or https://github.com/rocketraman/activator-akka-scala-guice/blob/master/src/test/scala/CountingActorSpec.scala

Answer (score 0):

So hey, here is a complicated HOW-TO. (Beware: Untested and thoroughly stupid code)

```
public class MyComplicatedGuiceModule extends AbstractModule {
  protected void configure() {
    // does some configuration stuff
  }

  @Provides
  @Named("RedToothPick")
  ToothPick provideRedToothPick() {
    ToothPick(Color.RED)
  }

  @Provides
  @Named("WhiteToothPick")
  ToothPick provideWithToothPick() {
    ToothPick(Color.WHITE)
  }
}
```

And to use this in your class, you would do something like this:

```
public class WildCleanToothService(@Named("RedToothPick") toothPick: ToothPick) {
}
```

Now, it is fair to argue: Why the complication? See how *less* lines the Scala code uses?

For me, the biggest benefits have been in testing the actual code. It boils down to: How do you test your companion object? What if it invoked some random service. How would we mock the service? Being able to plug-in dependencies makes it possible to test them individually and easily.

Comment: The big big thing that I completely missed is that the ONLY way to get an Injected Class is from within an Injected class. (That is apparently what is meant or at least inferred by the "turtles all the way down" metaphor.) The moment you grok that concept the rest becomes much easier. Until you do however it appears that your doomed to forever get null references for any Guice incantations you attempt outside of that "stack of turtles". So this turns out the answer is not to focus on how to get the toothpick but how to get the stack of turtles from which a toothpick can actually be requested.

Comment: That is partially true. In the sense, Guice does not *restrict* you from getting any specific class anywhere in the hierarchy. In fact, I think the rule to think about is that if you want to have a class 'injected', all of its dependencies should also be 'injected'. For instance, it is possible for me to create a standalone class, obtain reference to an injector and either (a) Inject the class and Guice will fill the dependencies for me (b) Create the instance myself, ensuring that all the dependencies are managed by me.